# Print message when invalid data entered in console application using switch C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, console-application

Im trying to write a basic calculator with a main menu and sub menu.

The code is working fine when a valid entry is inputted, but I want an error message to be displayed and then return the user to the main menu when invalid data is entered.

This is what I have done so far. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 // Main method (only to be used for mainmenu() execution)
    MainMenu();

 }

 // Main Menu method
 static void MainMenu()
 {
 // Declaring variables
 // Selection variable, used in user's input to get to the desired operation
    int sel;
    char letter;

 // Main menu styling
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("********************");
    Console.WriteLine("1- Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("2- Exit Calculator");
    Console.Write("Please enter your option here:  ");

 // Converting user's input to sel's type (byte)
    sel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
 // Processing sel
    switch (sel)
    {
       case 1:                    
       // Execute Addition()
          SecondMenu();
          break;

       case 2:
          Console.ReadLine();
          break;

       default:
          Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!"); //Catch                    
          break;                    
    }
 }

 static void SecondMenu()
 {
    char sel2; // Selection variable, used in user's input to get to the desired operation

 // Display Menu Options
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("********************");
    Console.WriteLine("A. Addition");
    Console.WriteLine("S. Substraction");
    Console.WriteLine("D. Division");
    Console.WriteLine("********************");
    Console.Write("Please enter your option here:   ");
 // Converting user's input to sel's type (byte)
    sel2 = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
 // Processing sel
    switch (sel2)
    {          
       case 'a':                    
    // Execute Addition()
       Addition();
       break;

       case 's':
    // Execute Substraction()
       Substraction();
       break;

       case 'd':
    // Execute Division()
       Division();
       break;                
    }
 }

    // Addition Method
    static void Addition()
    {
        // Declaring variables
        double num1, num2, res;

        Console.Write("Please enter the first number: ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        // Processing numbers into one variable
        res = num1 + num2;
        // Printing out the result
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT:  " +res);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        MainMenu();
    }

    // Substraction Method
    static void Substraction()
    {
        // Declaring variables
        double num1, num2, res; 

        Console.Write("Please enter the first number:  ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        // Processing numbers into one variable
        res = num1 - num2;
        // Printing out the result
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT:  " + res);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        MainMenu();
    }



    // Division
    static void Division()
    {
        // Declaring variables
        double num1, num2, res; 

        Console.Write("Please enter the first number: ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");
        // Getting user's input and converting it
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        // Processing numbers into one variable
        res = num1 / num2;
        // Printing out the result
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT:  " + res);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        MainMenu();
   }
```

Comment: huh? you must have some codes too.

Comment: could you add some source code?

Comment: _this is what i have so far_ can you post some code where you facing issue to achieve what you looking for ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Ive added the code

Comment: @simonH. Ive uploaded my code. its messy I know but I want it functional then I will tidy it up

Comment: @Agent_Orange I have uploaded the code

Comment: You don't need to ping every person...

As far as I can see, you print something, when there is a wrong input (the default case in the switch statement).
Can you clarify your question?

Comment: you can experiment using `do{}while(isCorrectEntry)`

Comment: @hellow instead of printing the error message the console just crashes. the values need to be 1 or 2, it cannot be alphabetical.

Comment: @rahulAgarwal could you give me an example? just the basics so that i can wrap my head around how these functions would interact

Answer (score 2):

You could just do it like this

```
    static void SecondMenu()
    {

        char sel2; // Selection variable, used in user's input to get to the desired operation

        // Display Menu Options
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("A. Addition");
        Console.WriteLine("S. Substraction");
        Console.WriteLine("D. Division");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.Write("Please enter your option here:   ");
        sel2 = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (sel2)
        {

            case 'a':
                Calc(1);
                break;

            case 's':
                Calc(2);
                break;

            case 'd':
                Calc(3);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong entry! Try again");
                MainMenu();
                return;
        }
    }

    static void Calc(int f)
    {
        double num1, num2, res;
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the first number: ");

            num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Please enter the second number: ");

            num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (f)
            {
                case 1:
                    res = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    res = num1 - num2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    res = num1 / num2;
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong entry! Try again");
                    MainMenu();
                    return;

            }
            Console.WriteLine("RESULT:  " + res);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            MainMenu();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong entry! Try again");
            MainMenu();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: To make sure the first menu wont crash, sorround it with a try catch block

```
    try
        {
            sel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (sel)
            {
                case 1:
                    SecondMenu();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
                    MainMenu();
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
            MainMenu();
        }
```

Your problem was, that it tried to parse a char into an int, what is not possible.

Comment: Oh Ok, will try this but how would i get the first instance working the same.

Comment: @NicBarthow just add a Default case as i did in the secondmenu

Comment: So I tried this with the first menu but I think its not working due to the fact that i used int. Im trying to understand why its so different .. what am i missing

Comment: When I try to use the Try catch on the first menu, its not reconising the SecondMenu option. Would that mean I need to change the coding to how you suggested for the secondmenu format or is there another way to  get the number options working ?

Comment: @NicBarthow Make sure to place the TryCatchBlock at the right position! You could copy the given code and change it to your desires after you understood how it actually works

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for the tip. Im going to try it on another program and see how it works before implementing the code. I think i need to brush up on what Int can be used for first

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `MainMenu()` method in the `default` part of the `switch` in it.

```
 switch (sel)
            {        

                case 1:

                    // Execute Addition()
                    SecondMenu();
                    break;

                case 2:
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format!");
                    MainMenu(); 
                    //Catch

                    break;    
            }
```

It is also recommended to have a condition to exit the program (like a maximum number of invalid inputs).

Comment: Am i using the right method before the switch cases? sel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); ?

Comment: yes @NicBarthow. It is correct. After pressing ENTER, what you have written will be changed to an integer and if the entered input is not valid (mistake in typing, etc) it will throw an exception. If you want to avoid exceptions you can use int.TryParse() method. Check it here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works, but you'll have to adjust accordingly to fit your requirements:

```
int sel;
char letter;
bool valid = false;

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("********************");
    Console.WriteLine("1- Calculator");
    Console.WriteLine("2- Exit Calculator");
    Console.Write("Please enter your option here:  ");

    sel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (sel)
    {
        case 1:
            SecondMenu();
            break;

        case 2:
            Environment.Exit(0); 
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");     
            break;
    }
}
while (valid != true);
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would work as  case 1 doesnt function

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by 'doesnt function'. What is the _actual_ output of your program? How does it differ from the _expected_ output?

Comment: The SecondMenu(); is not recognized as a valid option and causes the application to crash.. I will upload the message later

Answer (score 0):

You can either write the switch case in another method and call the main method at the default case after printing the error message,
OR
Use a do-while loop,
Inside do, write the switch cases and put a condition at while to exit the calculator.
For example: 'Enter -1 to exit the calculator' and condition in while x!=-1

Answer (score 0):

Try having a play with this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainMenu();
}

static void MainMenu()
{
    int sel = -1;
    while (sel != 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("1- Calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("2- Exit Calculator");
        Console.Write("Please enter your option here:  ");

        sel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (sel == 1)
        {
            SecondMenu();
        }
        else if (sel != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!"); //Catch                    
        }
    }
}

static void SecondMenu()
{
    var options = new Dictionary<char, Func<double, double, double>>()
    {
        { 'a', (x, y) => x + y },
        { 's', (x, y) => x - y },
        { 'd', (x, y) => x / y },
    };

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.WriteLine("A. Addition");
        Console.WriteLine("S. Substraction");
        Console.WriteLine("D. Division");
        Console.WriteLine("********************");
        Console.Write("Please enter your option here:   ");

        char sel = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        if (options.ContainsKey(sel))
        {
            Calculate(options[sel]);
            break;
        }
    }
}

static void Calculate(Func<double, double, double> operation)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number: ");
    double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number: ");
    double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    double res = operation(num1, num2);
    Console.WriteLine("RESULT:  " + res);
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```